# ios two transitions/presentations in navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` which includes a `UISearchController`. This then segues to a `UIViewController` followed by another `UIViewController`. From the second view I would like transition back to the `UITableViewController` by first hiding the UISearchController and then popping the two views.

To achieve that I have:

```
 var stackViews = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count
 var musicTableController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[stackViews!-3] as! MusicTableController
 musicTableController.resultSearchController.active = false
 self.navigationController?.popToViewController(musicTableController, animated: true)
```

This however results in the error

```
popToViewController:transition: called on <UINavigationController 0x7fb42a575550> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

I'm guessing I need to the pop the view after the resultsSearchController transition has completed some how.

Swift, ios8, xcode6.4

Answer (score 2):

You can call `dismiss(_:_:)` on the `UISearchController` instead of setting `isActive` to false.

```
if searchController.isActive {
    self.searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        // Play segue, dismiss or pop ...
    })
} else {
   // Play segue, dismiss or pop ...
}
```

Comment: Why have your wrapped this in `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Comment: UIKit classes should be used only from the main thread. Dispach may not be needed here, I think it was needed in the specific case I was working on (18 months ago).

Comment: That's true - but there's nothing in the question to indicate that this has anything to do with a background thread. It may have been required in your case, but you have to remember that people just copy these answers verbatim - and this bad habit gets propagated.